# Handling Apostrophe's from ODP.net to send to Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, odp.net

I will be sending some information to a stored procedure that will put information to a database.
The stored procedure builds the query dynamically so I have to be careful of what I send down to it.
I use to just pull any malicious characters out of the required parameters either on my front end (I am using asp.net MVC) or on my web-service.  That works, but what if I needed to input a name like O'brian for instance?  Or can't?  I will need to be able to input that into oracle.  I could just wrap q[] around those particular parameters when they are being dynamically built, but I don't think that will work.  Does odp .net have any special method calls that could magically handle that special case?
or will I have to specifically code that in myself?

Comment: What is the stored procedure doing? It is rare that you really need to build the query dynamically. If you do, though, you should still be using bind variables rather than concatenating string literals together. If you use bind variables, you wouldn't need to worry about escaping characters.  You also wouldn't need to worry about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: when you say bind variables, are you talking about in the Oracle stored procedure?

Comment: @JustinCave - if the stored procedure is building dynamic sql then he absolutely needs to worry about escaping and injection attacks.  If you're dynamically building sql, then injection is a concern, period.

Comment: @b_levitt - Assuming that, after using bind variables for values like "O'Brian" the stored procedure was still concatenating input from the caller to generate the SQL statement, you're right that SQL injection is still possible, you just wouldn't have to worry about values like "O'Brian" being escaped.  It's rare, though, that a stored procedure would need to operate that way.  The vast majority of those cases would be handled by adding appropriate `DBMS_ASSERT` calls rather than escaping characters.

Comment: @Justin Cave - Agreed.  We are on the same page then.  Awesome tip on DBMS_ASSERT (specifically DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL).  You should post that as an answer as it covers both #2 and #3 of my answer.

Comment: Correction, ENQUOTE_LITERAL only covers #2.  It asserts #3 but does not escape the quotes for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODP.net provides an interface between your .net code and Oracle.  If you're building dynamic sql AFTER control has been passed to the proc, than there's not a lot that odp.net can do for you.

The danger is the string, and in this case varchar.  It's really only a string or similar that somebody could get some extra sql injected into your code. As long as a bind variable is always a single string (ie, one set of un-escaped single quotes), than there's not a lot a malicious user could do.

So I think there's a few rules that would allow you could consider this safe:

**1) Use varchar/clob parameters only where absolutely necessary.**

**2) Varchar/clob bind values should always be wrapped in single quotes within the resulting sql:**

Good:

```
'where myval=''' || p_my_val || ''''
```

Bad:

```
'where myval=' || p_my_val
```

**3) Replace any single quote with two single quotes within the string**

```
'where myval=''' || replace(p_my_val, '''', '''''') || ''''
```

I think at that point you would have mitigated your risk.  Below is a complete working example from the oracle side.  I've also included a bind variable "l_fname" within the sql and populated with "using" in case you have other variables that are always in the query (vs conditionally appended) and always in the same order.

```
--create the ref cursor (simulates cmd.Parameters.Add)
var c refcursor;
--vvvvvvvvv simulates your stored proc vvvvvvvvvvvv
declare 
  l_lname varchar2(200) :='O''brian';
  l_fname varchar2(200) :='Bob';
  l_sql varchar2(2000);
begin
  l_sql := 'select * from dual where dummy!=:l_fname ' || 'and dummy!=''' || replace(l_lname, '''','''''') || '''';
  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
  open :c for l_sql using replace(l_fname, '''', '''''');
end;
--^^^^^^^^^ ends yoru stored proc ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/
--debugging within oracle only:
print c;
```

**Also consider whether you need dynamic sql at all.  Nearly any logic you do outside of the final sql string can be done within it instead**, ie:

```
if( p_my_var is not null ) then
  p_sql = p_sql || ' and myval = ''' || replace(p_my_val, '''', '''''') || ''''
```

Could be

```
and p_my_val is null or myval=p_my_val
```

I highly recommend the above in SQL server.  I also recommend doing it in Oracle but it doesn't short circuit as well as it does in sql server since the bind value is not considered in the execution plan, causing it to be less than optimal in some cases (at least in 10g).  In such cases, use the following instead:

```
and myval=decode(p_my_val, null, col1, p_my_val);
```

Comment: Justin Cave pointed out the DBMS_ASSERT package which contains the DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL function which would effectively reduce my #2 and #3 to 'where myval=' || DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITTERAL(p_my_val)

Comment: I thought I got around the problem, by simpling appending a second aposrophe to escape the apostrophe in the stored procedure, but now it is adding two apostrophes where before it only had one, and the stored procedure would crash.  This is frustrating.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a working script.  I also retract my comment about DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL.  While it does add the beginning and ending quotes, it does not escape quotes.  It only throws an error if the string contains them.